# Having trouble getting a Greasemonkey script to focus on the textbox on VirusTotal.com

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to get a Greasemonkey script to automatically focus on the textbox on [this page](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/url).

This simple script below has worked on many other sites, but not on this one:

---

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Focus On The First Textbox - Site Specific
// @namespace      n/a
// @description    Focuses the first textbox on the page.  Include specific pages that you want it to work.
// @include        https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/url
// ==/UserScript==

var box = document.evaluate("//input[@type='text']",document,null,9,null).singleNodeValue;

if(box!=null && box) {
box.focus();
}
```

---

What are they doing differently on this page and how do I need to change my script to get it to work?

Comment: You need to wait for the element to exist first. Also, it's nested in a *bunch* of shadow roots.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thank you.  I'm very new to this, so the complexities of this URL's page is not something I've had to deal with before.  What do you recommend?  Is the only thing I need to do is wait, but otherwise, my current code would work?